# I'm unable to inject a style with an "!important" rule

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, dom

I tried to inject a style using this code:

```
document.body.style.color='green!important';
```

Per [the CSS cascade ref](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html), by applying the `!important` rule I can trump origin and specificity.

I tried to inject this using Firefox Firebug into www.google.com however no luck.

How do I inject a foreground color with an `!important` rule?

Comment: Did you try with a space ? `document.body.style.color = "green !important";`

Answer (score 109):

Per the spec, if you want to set the priority, not just the value, you have to use `setProperty`, like so:

```
document.body.style.setProperty ("color", "green", "important");
```

Comment: IE9+ only. Apparently you can use setAttribute instead for <IE9 (not sure how far back). Could someone clarify if it's possible to use setAttribute to specify the priority as well, it's unclear to me if you can.

Comment: @RTF: Assuming the implementation is correct it should be possible - `!important` can legally appear in inline style declarations.

Comment: @RTF https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536739%28v=vs.85%29.aspx IE8 appears to support `setAttribute`

Comment: @BoltClock, For which specs?

Comment: @Pacerier: css-style-attr, which simply follows the same grammar used in the rest of CSS.

Answer (score 11):

```
element.style.cssText = 'color:green !important';
```

should work for you.

Comment: That works if there are no other styles set on the element, otherwise it will overwrite any other styles on the element and lose them.

Comment: if there are other styles on the element, just concatenate your styles: `element.style.cssText += ';color: green !important;'` and you're safe on browsers that support `cssText` property! :)

Comment: Method (i.e. `... += ...`) given by @guari works but only in upgrading the priority of a style to "!important".  Downgrading from '!important', on the other hand, will fail.  i.e.  `element.style.cssText += 'color:blue'`, will fail while `element.style.cssText += 'color:blue !important'` will work.

Answer (score 3):

style.cssText is the only way to add !important.

```
<script>
   document.body.style.cssText='color: red !important;'
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

all answers are great but they all assumed the `value` of the attribute is `fixed`,, what if not

take look at my solution

```
this.style.setProperty("color", $(this).css('color'), "important");
```

instead of `hand writing` the value, I got it using jquery `$(this).css('attr')`

Answer (score 1):

I would like to pose that it may not be working not so much due to any error in code (excepting the space) but more because modifying the body tag isn't a specific enough element, class, or what have you to create the desired effect.

Like for instance the page text of a search result has a class of "st".
all search results are each encapsulated in an 
`<li>` 
tag.

So some code to such effect might look like this:

```
var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('st');
for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    arr[i].style.color="green";
}
```

Comment: hanks for the answers

tried to inject document.body.style.color = "green !important"; onto bbc.co.uk using firefox firebug but no luck :( 

had a look at the style in firebug,  it is due to 
* {
color: #505050;
} 

can't see "!important" qualifier in source so i am baffled

@Ahren, i thought source (user important) trumped all other rules no matter what the specificity was?
Ref:http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html (6.4.1 cascading order)

& if i injected !important, it would be a user important declaration  overruling  all other cad rules

did not know about "accept functionality" :D

Answer (score 0):

Use only this:

```
document.body.style.color="green";
```

you can not have to use important in this way. Anyway as Fatal pointed out, this will not work, when there is directly important rule in css stylesheet, that you need to  override.

In that way, you have to dynamicaly create stylesheet and ad it inside head:

```
function addNewStyle(newStyle) {
   var styleElement = document.getElementById('styles_js');
   if (!styleElement) {
       styleElement = document.createElement('style');
       styleElement.type = 'text/css';
       styleElement.id = 'styles_js';
       document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleElement);
   }
   styleElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newStyle));
}
```

Then you can update style just like that

```
addNewStyle('body {color:green !important;}')
```

Comment: This will be beaten by a CSS style with ID-Selector and !important. HTML: `<body id="illwin" style="color:green;">
        This is a test!
    </body>` CSS: `#illwin {
    color: red !important;
}` This will result in red colored text. http://jsfiddle.net/C6zH2/

Answer (score -1):

i need to keep !important for the following code how to do

```
<script> var size = $(window).width(); 
if(size >="1900" && size <="2890"){
 $(document).ready(function(){ $(".myMove").click(function(){ $(".hqnblogo").animate({ left:'-22% ', top: '67%', height:'7%', }); $(".hqnbnaturalslogo").animate({ left: '86%', top: '20px', height:'7%', }); }); }); } </script>?
```

Comment: Hey, Welcome stopping by at SO. However, this answer doesn't meet SO answering guidelines, is not clear.