# How can I add the !important tag to the css produced by this javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

How can I add the !important css tag to the transform/translate part of the following js?

```
animationProperties.elements.css( {
    'transition-duration': animationProperties.duration + 'ms',
    'transform': 'translate(' + animationProperties.amount + ')'
} );
```

I have tried a few things, such as:

```
'transform': 'translate(' + animationProperties.amount + ') !important'
```

and

```
'transform': 'translate(' + animationProperties.amount + !important')'
```

...but I can't seem to get it.

Comment: have a look at this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917608/im-unable-to-inject-a-style-with-an-important-rule

Comment: This seems to be jQuery, as the `css()` method does not exist in the plain JavaScript DOM API.