# Style.display = 'none' does not work on BBC.com Overlay Element

Tags: javascript, html, css

So this might be an odd question. But I tried to hide a certain HTML element on the bbc.com website with using `element.style.display = 'none !important'` in my Google Chrome Console. Strangely it does not hide the element as I would expect it.
Maybe it is something minor and I am just overseeing something.

Here is the code I use:

```
var overlay = document.querySelector("div[class='fc-dialog-overlay']");
overlay.style.display = 'none !important';
```

I do not get an error and if I inspect the element it also contains the new property and looks like `<div class="fc-dialog-overlay" style="display: none;"></div>`, but it can still be seen.
The same problem occurs with several other elements like the `class='fc-consent-root'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note**: Don't do the `setAttribute` thing below, use `setProperty` as shown in [this answer to the earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7919637/157247). *(I'll delete this answer when/if it's un-accepted by the OP.)*

---

You're specifying an invalid property value; `!important` can be used in style *rules* but not in the specific values you assign via the `style` object. I'm surprised you're seeing the `display: none` in the `style` area. I don't with Chrome or Firefox when I do that (perhaps it was left over from having done `.display = "none"` and not seeing it work?):

```js
const overlay = document.getElementById("example");
overlay.style.display = "none !important";
```

```html
<div id="example">x</div>
<div>y</div>
```

If I right-click `x` and look at it, it doesn't have a `style` at all, even after the code runs.

You can still do it, you just have to assign to the entire `style` attribute so you get full rules parsing:

```js
const overlay = document.getElementById("example");
overlay.setAttribute(
    "style",
    overlay.getAttribute("style") + "; display: none !important"
);
```

```css
#example {
    display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="example">x</div>
<div>y</div>
```

Note that it works even though I have a conflicting `!important` rule applied via a stylesheet. That's because a stylesheet `!important` rule overrides an inline style unless the inline style *also* has `!important`.

Comment: Alternative: [`overlay.style.setProperty("display", "none", "important");`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty#parameters).

Comment: Thank you @t.j. it worked perfectly. And also thank you for the explanation. Just one more question to have a better understanding- What do you mean with rules parsing?

Comment: @SebastianSimon - Oh wow. TIL! That's not just *an* alternative, that's a **much, much** better one. Post it as an answer?

Comment: @Peter - In a stylesheet or `style` attribute when you do `display: none !important` the `!important` isn't part of the value, the value is just `none`. The `!important` part is a priority indicator. When you do `.style.display = "x"` you can't specify the priority indicator, the property only allows actual values. That whole thing (`display: none !important`) is a *style rule* and it's parsed into its individual components. But when just a value is expected, that parsing isn't done. Side note: use `setProperty` as Sebastian showed, rather than my answer above. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Actually, this seems to be a duplicate of [I'm unable to inject a style with an "!important" rule](/q/7917608/4642212).

Comment: @Peter - Your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7919637/157247). Would you do me a favor and un-accept the answer above? Thanks. Happy coding!