# CSS/SCSS/bootstrap :: override print settings in bootstrap :: change background:transparent ! important to a color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overriding, sass

I have a problem with the bootstrap CSS/print.

In bootstrap CSS (reset.css) everything is cleared for printing

```
@media print {
  * {
    text-shadow: none !important;
    color: black !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }
}
```

But I have to print several lines in color. My table looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="task-summary">
        <div id="process-summary">
            <table class="table table-condensed">
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="success">
                        <td>
```

I embeded this into my code, but it does not work:

```
@media print {

  #task-summary{
    .success{
      background-color: #DFF0D7 !important;
    }
  }
}
```

I've already tried if the css is excepted by using display: none .. it works (line is not displayed) and seems to be on the right place.

Does someone have an idea how I can manage to override the bootstrap css command, without editing the reset.css of bootstrap?

Comment: Your browser may be trying to be clever and refusing to print background colours. Check your browser settings.

Comment: Your user's browser settings will override this, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3894013/1064286

Comment: thanks sevenseacat, you have given me the right directions... fixed it for chrome7safari with -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact; and will now google to find a solution for IE

Comment: Check your nestings...

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. When you print the page the `background-color: ...;` option doesn't work at table rows. Change the CSS-Selector to:

```
@media print {

  #task-summary .success td {
    background-color: #DFF0D7 !important;

    /* add this line for better support in chrome */ 
    -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
  }
}
```

Everything should work after this changes.

Comment: It was the "-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;" line that got this working for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
@media print {
    .success {
      background-color: #DFF0D7 !important;
    }    
}
```

Or

```
@media print {
    #task-summary .success {
      background-color: #DFF0D7 !important;
    }  
}
```

Or

```
@media print {
    #task-summary > #process-summary .success {
      background-color: #DFF0D7;
    }
}
```