# Print HTML table background color with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If I use Bootstrap `table` class on a table, print preview doesn't show background color for `tr`.

My code

```css
@media print {
  .bg-danger {
    background-color: #f2dede !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="bg-danger">
    <td>DIV</td>
  </div>

  <table class="table">
    <tr class="bg-danger">
      <td>TR 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="danger">
      <td>TR 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #f2dede !important;">
      <td>TR 3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

On screen, all is red but on print preview only the `div` element is red.

If I remove the `table` class, everything works (except I need table style).

My configuration : IE11 and Windows 7.

Is there a trick to print the background color ?

**Note:** The indicated duplicate ([CSS @media print issues with background-color;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893986/css-media-print-issues-with-background-color)) is not the issue here, my settings are checked to print background colors. Also, I can print color for several *other* elements.

**Answer :**

Thanks to @Ted comments, I overrided `td` style for `table` class :

```
<style type="text/css">
  @media print {
    .bg-danger {
      background-color: #f2dede !important;
    }
    
    .table td {
      background-color: transparent !important;
    }
  }
</style>
```

Comment: My IE settings for printing background are already checked.

Comment: Bootstrap explicitly sets the background to white for printing--this is in their CSS: `@media print {
  .table td,
  .table th {
    background-color: #fff !important;
  }
}`. Write your override like theirs.

Comment: Ok I can't answer my question now...But @Ted your solution works !! I overrided ``tr`` but I didn't think for ``td``. Thanks !!!
I added ``.table td { background-color: transparent !important; }`` in the ``print`` section.

Comment: @Ted want to convert your comment to an answer? Reopened the question :)

Comment: Worked great for me on Chrome, huge help, thanks so much

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Bootstrap explicitly sets the background to white for printing--this is in their CSS:

```
@media print { 
    .table td, .table th { 
        background-color: #fff !important; 
    } 
}
```

Write your override like theirs and you should be good to go.

Comment: So the best answer is to edit the bootstrap file and remove the !important (everwhere!  - it should only ever be used if required - not to 'gee if you follow my style then changing it for any reason is bad, so I'm going to force you to use !important everywhere!)   - Or option 2, use !important all over your code to override their over use of !Important?  Is there a simple file I can just not include to get this or do I really have to hack it?

Comment: I am trying to get a page to print like a form that I'm duplicating - so I'd like to simply be able to view on the screen what is going to print.  Div's not white, tables not white, images show with the background I set in the Div.  And not have to edit everything and put in 500 !Importants and override everything for printing!

Answer (score 2):

There is not. By default they don't print. It's a browser option that can't be overcome by CSS/JS etc.

There IS this, which force colors...allegedly in Chrome

```
-webkit-print-color-adjust
```

Which is listed as BUGGY support ONLY for chrome, and not supported in other browsers.

Comment: But the ``div`` element is printing well. And if I remove ``class="table"``, my table is printing well. There is an issue only if I use ``class="table"``.

Comment: I can't use Chrome, my page is displayed in the WPF WebBrowser component which use IE

Answer (score 2):

Adding onto @Ted's answer, the following will override the default bootstrap `background-color !important` rule:

```
@media print {
    table tr.highlighted > td {
        background-color: yellow !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace **table** class to **table-print**

By using this CSS code

```
.table-print {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    color: #212529;
}

    .table-print thead th {
        vertical-align: bottom;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #dee2e6;
    }

    .table-print th, .table-print td {
        padding: 0.75rem;
        vertical-align: top;
        border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6;
    }
 .table-print .thead-dark th {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #343a40;
    border-color: #454d55;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a table th header row and styled it like this

```
.table th {
        background-color: #2D3347 !important;
        color: #fff !important
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think better way is to use more specific css selector

```
<style>
@media print {
   .table td.cell {
     background-color: blue !important;
   }
}
</style>

<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td class="cell">TR 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all suggested solutions here (and in many other questions), such as applied `background-color: #000 !important;` both in stylesheet and inline, or set

```
@media print {
  * {
    color-adjust: exact !important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
    print-color-adjust: exact !important;
  }
}
```

, even combined them together, but nothing worked.

As you said above, everything works except `<table>`, so the *easiest trick* is to wrap-up anything inside `<th>` or `<td>` with a `<div>` (you can adjust padding to make it display same as prior).

e.g.

```
...
<th><div>Col title here...</div></th>
...
<td><div>Content here...</div></td>
...
```

For me, problem was solved by doing this "*hack*".

Hope this help!