# Printing a div's content using JavaScript without background-color stylize

Tags: javascript, html, css

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
function printDiv(divID) {
  var divElements = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;

    var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;

    document.body.innerHTML = 
      "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" + 
      divElements + "</body>";

    window.print();

    document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;

}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="printablediv"> 
<table class="table table-hover table-striped" id="bootstrap-table">
         <tr bgcolor="#E4E4E4">
                <th>#ID</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>200</td>
                <td>janedoe</td>
                <td>Yane</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
</table>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="javascript:printDiv('printablediv')" style="float:right"/>
```

After the button is clicked the JavaScript should print the table but lose the `background-color` in the progress.

I have tried to modify the CSS-style but it just erases all the styles of the table and prints it even a bit too simple.

Comment: add style media print with background

Comment: you can just use a separate CSS file for printing, as you can see here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmedia.shtml

Comment: some one plz edit my code... its not working

Comment: i tried many, media quries but not work.... plz help some one

Comment: this SO link may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893986/css-media-print-issues-with-background-color

Comment: Are you planning to use this for more printable items, or will the thing you want to print always be called `printablediv`?

Comment: yup...................

Comment: but not printing, background color

Answer (score 1):

That's a really strange way of printing, but if the only issue you see is that it's not printing the background color, you might be out of luck. In most browsers (all?) printing of background colors of tables is controlled by the print dialog, not the by webpage itself. This is to save ink, so by default, it's turned off. What you need to do is click the `print backgrounds` checkbox (wording will vary with browser/operating system) in the print dialog box that comes up.

As far as I'm aware, this cannot be reliably controlled programatically. Sorry.

I've heard that you can use the following CSS, but it's really only properly supported in Safari and buggy in Chrome.

```
body {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
}
```

Comment: its first time i was not getting answer from stackflow