# Print HTML table with background colors in CHROMIUM browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I have a panel in my html page that is to be printed on click of the print button. The print button uses window.print() for this. I have a table in my page which has some background colors to it. The color coding is kinda important to my application while printing.

I added -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; css to my table style classes and it was working as expected in Chrome browser.

However, in CHROMIUM browser, the text which is in the table appears with a white background in the PDF. Please refer the snapshot below for your reference.

[image]

Expected result

[image]

Current output

I am really stuck here. :(
Please help!! Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I am not near my chromium stick to test, but maybe using `color-adjust: exact`??

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. It is giving me economy print for table. Could you please help me here? Really in middle of soup this time :(

Comment: Well set a print stylesheet rules that makes it readable until you find a solution.

Comment: Is it a bug in CHROMIUM browser? I am not sure.