# How can I keep heading colors when printing a web page?

Tags: html, css

I have a basic web page with a dark background and light text. Printing not only darkens the paragraph text, but the heading text too.

I would like to keep the heading text-colors. I have already tried:

- An `@media print` rule
- Adding `media="all"` to the stylesheet link.
- Two seperate `css` stylesheet links. One with `media="screen"` and the other `media="print"`

Neither Firefox nor Chrome have any effect.

- `-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;` does work, but [only in Chrome/Webkit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust#Browser_compatibility).

I am not trying to preserve any background-colors, only the text-colors of heading elements. Please see [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4jacuL04/). I am not using any bootstrap or Javascript on the page.

Comment: I think there is not enough contrast between the colors you chose and the black background, this will never look good in print

Comment: I'm using the colorscheme on a number of documents, I actually have a slight text shadow too, so it is readable.

Comment: Have you seen the answer to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893986/css-media-print-issues-with-background-color

Comment: I have indeed, thanks, but I do not want to print background colors.

Comment: its something about to config the printer for supporting the background graphics. It is in the print option or properties.

Comment: see the Browser [compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust) of `-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;`

Comment: @FrayneKonok I have tried that setting but it prints the background. I merely want to preserve the foreground color of certain elements. I have linked the compatibility of that property in my question already.

Comment: set up a new style when you are fire for printing the page.
the style applied to the foreground color only with `!important`

Comment: `!important` has no effect, thanks for trying.

Comment: Use frayns webkit-color-adjust with @media print to remove the background.

Comment: @seahorsepip webkit-color-adjust is not an option due to browser incompatibility.

Comment: If I attempt to print the example you provided, it will retain the text color so I am not sure what is the problem? http://puu.sh/n7w4I/64071198ed.png now if you disable the background the colors will be darkened because a whitish text on white background is not readable, seems chrome tries to take care of that issue by itself