# Bootstrap page print

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, printing

I want to print a bootstrap page. Here is my page layout

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="image/logo.png">          
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container" id="student">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h1>Student</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-6" id="date">
                <form class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="focusedInput"> <b>Date:</b></label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="focusedInput" type="text" placeholder="DD Month Year">
                    </div>
                </form>         
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also I've css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "myfont";
    src: url("../fonts/opensans/OpenSans-Regular 2.ttf");
}
body{
    font-family: "myfont";
    /*-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;*/
}

img{
    width: 150px;
}
#student{
    margin-top: 50px;
}
#date{
    background: black;
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Problem is: css is not loading properly. I tried searching stackoverflow but did not get any exact solution. How can I do that?
Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wc6rga7o/

Comment: What is your @media print css ?

Comment: Tried adding @media pls check https://jsfiddle.net/wc6rga7o/1/

Comment: Try is standard beahvior of navigators : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893986/css-media-print-issues-with-background-color

Comment: Tried not working

Comment: Is the black background not working ?

Comment: Yes. black background and grid not working

Comment: Please read this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893986/css-media-print-issues-with-background-color

Comment: @MathieuDormeval, I read the ques again but still not solved.

Comment: Beacause it's impossible, this is the default behavior of the browser, it is up to the user to choose whether or not to display backgrounds

Answer (score 1):

try

```
@media print {
    /* Your styles here */
    body{
           color: #111111;
    }
    #date{
           -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact!important;
    }

}
```

updated your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wc6rga7o/2/

[image]

Comment: try `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="bootstrap.min.css"> ` notice `media="print"`

Comment: This is standard the behavior of navigator