# Background color cant be printed in @media print

Tags: html, css

I've read the different questions here about the css issues in background color when printing. I tried to follow the steps and the solutions presented especially here [CSS @media print issues with background-color;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893986/css-media-print-issues-with-background-color#) but I still can't print the background color.

Do I  have other choices to print the page with the background color?

Here is my code in style for the body

```
body {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
    font-size:11px;
    color-adjust: exact !important;
    print-color-adjust: exact !important;
}
```

Comment: did you try the box shadow trick in your link?  Just tried it in firefox and it seems to work for me ([using firefox](http://fiddle.jshell.net/hmbx7d1e/3/show/light/) - couldn't load the frame in chrome)

Answer (score 2):

Browsers generally ask whether or not the user wishes to print background graphics, here's Chrome's print interface:

[image]

Unfortunately, there is no way to force this option to be enabled.

Comment: i tried this but still i cant print the background color