# CSS @page background-images on all pages?

Tags: html, css, printing

I want the same background image on every printed page. Anytime a page is needed because of overflow, it should have the same background image as the previous one.

I've been trying to do this

```
@page {
    size: US-Letter portrait;
    background-image: url("something.jpg");
    padding: 3in .5in .75in .5in;
}
```

But this doesn't work on any browser. Is this something that is simply not possible? Or is there some more tricks to it that I haven't yet found?

Comment: how was this resolved ? i'm stuck in the same situation

Answer (score 0):

This way of getting it done works:

```
@media print {
    body {
        background: url("something.jpg");
    }
}
```

Also ensure also your browser settings about your printer [let you to print a background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3894013/4375327). (In Firefox, it's the option tab in the dialog letting you choose your printer.)

Comment: That will not work though. It will print the background once. But it you have multiple pages, the background will not repeat for each page.

Comment: @LanFeusT, it **does** work, the background **repeats** for each page, I just did the test (Firefox).

Answer (score -1):

For printing you might want to use the [`@media print`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Printing) media query instead of [`@page`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page) or combine them. Also the [`size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page/size) property doesn't seem to have a valid value.

```
@media print {
  @page {
    size: letter portrait;
    background-image: url("something.jpg");
    padding: 3in .5in .75in .5in;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing the size property. I don't think I need to wrap it in the media query as @page is meant for printing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page I did wrap it just to check and confirmed it still doesn't work.

Comment: Actually reading the @page description, it doesn't seem to support background-images at all...

Comment: I can confirm that @page does not support background-image