# Print background image on every page (longread html)

Tags: css

When I print longread html, I can insert background image, but it's work only on the first page. How I can insert bg image on every page?

```
@media print {
  body {
    background-image: url("something.jpg");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a selector as well to apply the background to:

```css
@media print {
    body {
        background-image: url("something.jpg");
    }
}
```

Please be aware that you cannot change printer settings - printing background images is usually disabled.

See answers here:
[CSS @page background-images on all pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54523204/css-page-background-images-on-all-pages)

Or google yourself:
stackoverflow print background image on every page

Comment: Yes, I forgot body in question. Your example is right, but it's work only on the first page.

Comment: See linked answer