# I am not being able to print the css even after using media-print

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, next.js

I am trying to make a format of a marksheet where I have used few css and I need them in print format as well. I have succeded pretty much. I am able to print all the styling except the background color in the table head. The styling is there while the web page is loaded but dissappears when I try to print it. I would be grateful if anyone could solve this for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893986/css-media-print-issues-with-background-color

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can print everything except the background.

If you are using IE, please try the following:

print preview ( right click on document -> print preview ), go to settings and there is option "print background color and images", select that option and try.

If you are using Chrome, please try the following:

Ctrl-P (print) > under more settings > options (tick background graphics)

Comment: I tried doing this as well but didnt work for me. p.s I used chrome. and i have created a print button in the webpage itself which triggers the printing function.

Comment: If you do not use your print button, but use the chrome's print function (and use my suggested method), what will be the result ?

Comment: the result is same additionally the other css  also wont function as desired if I use the chromes print function

Comment: Did you include the media="print" parameter in your css inclusion clause ? <link href="screen.css" media="screen"> <link href="print.css" media="print">